# Can I test a website locally through iOS?

Tags: ios, apache, xampp, localhost, dropbox

This is a very specific question. I really hope you guys can help me out. 
I am making a website (duh), but I am always on the go. I've been having some issues with web hosting companies so I decided to make my website locally. 
As I've pointed out before, I'm always on my iPad, therefore, I can't always work on my site, since I use XAMPP to test out my website. 
All of my files are in DropBox, I rewrote some of XAMPP's files so that when I test them on the computer, it gets the files from DropBox. Since it's all on DropBox, am I able to test my site (with Apache and hopefully MySQL Databases) on my iOS device? Is there any other solution? (Note: I am not interested on buying anything else, such as the Surface Pro)

Comment: So, to clarify, you are developing locally, and only wish to **EDIT** the files that your local development site is using via DropBox? Or is the site itself publicly accessible?

Comment: Kind of, my site is not publicly accessible, only through DropBox, I can edit the files already, but I need to test the website through my iOS device, with all its PHP fucntions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! 
Codeanywhere gives me the functionality to edit my site on my phone, and test it (Using its tool 'DevBox')! 
 I still need internet and my files aren't in DropBox anymore but oh well, it works right? Hopefully this helps someone...